# Не работает transition - js - css

Tags: javascript, html, css

У блока с id `#navigation` не работает transition. Тем самым меню открывается моментально.

```js
var tog = 0;
var nav = document.getElementById('navigation');
nav.style.display = "none";
nav.style.width = "0px";

function opn() {
  if (tog == 0) {
    nav.style.display = "inline-block";
    nav.style.width = "200px"
    tog = 1;
  } else {
    nav.style.display = "none";
    nav.style.width = "0px"
    tog = 0;
  }
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: monoone;
  src: url('/fonts/RubikMonoOne-Regular.ttf');
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#menuhead {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.menui {
  margin: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  transition: 1s all;
}

.menui:hover {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  margin-top: 15px;
  color: #aaa;
  font-family: monoone;
}

.left {
  text-align: left;
}

#navigation {
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: 1s all;
}
```

```html
<div id="menuhead">

  <div class="left">
    <img src="/images/menu.svg" alt="открой меню" class="menui" onclick="opn()"></div>
  <span class="title">Название</span>
</div>
<div id="navigation">
  <img src="/images/menu.svg" alt="открой меню" class="menui" onclick="opn()">
</div>
```

Comment: display:none; не анимируется хоть через js хоть через css,  есть .fadeIn()  .fadeOut() так же opacity , и так же : hide() ,show()

Comment: внимательно посмотрите на код  там есть nav.style.width = "200px"

Comment: а так же display:none; а показываете его display:inline-block; може быть у вас конфликт стилей , замените либо по инструкциям jquery , либо скрывайте его через width + overflow

Comment: уже решил......

Comment: Ну и каким образом решил-то?..

Comment: анимация display none как говорили да, не анимируется. Для анимациия появления через css нужно использовать visibility: hidden; opacity: 0; для спрятанного и visibiliy: visible; opacity: 1'

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь jQuery.

```
$('.left').on(click, function() {
$('#navigation').toggle();
}
```